# Convertendo lista em float array

Tags: python, arquivo, lista, conversão

Estou trabalhando em uma importação de dados, que estão no formato, como no exemplo:

```
[-2.814285863362681, -2.814158589901394, -2.8123844084634873]
[-2.874285863362681, -2.054158589901394, -2.6523844084634873]

.
.
.
```

Utilizei esse código para importar, já removendo o '\n' com o strip()

```
with open(coeffs_csv) as inp:
        signals_coeffs_cluster = inp.readlines()
        signals_coeffs_cluster = [x.strip() for x in signals_coeffs_cluster]
```

Porém necessito destes dados no formato float e em array, então trabalhei no código para apenas a segunda linha:

```
signal_1.append(signals_coeffs_cluster[1])

signal_1 = [k.replace('[', '').replace(']', '') for k in signal_1]
```

E isso me retorna um tamanho 1, ou seja, está tudo concatenado dentro de signal_1, não consigo, por exemplo fazer signal_1[2], pois não existe a posição.

Como proceder para extrair uma linha do arquivo de entrada e separa-los em forma de float array individuais ?

```
array_1 = [-2.814285863362681, -2.814158589901394, -2.8123844084634873] 
array_2 = [-2.874285863362681, -2.054158589901394, -2.6523844084634873]
```

E assim por diante ?

**EDIT:**

Uso este código para exportar:

```
coeffs = cA3.tolist()

    with open(coeffs_csv, "a") as output:
        json.dump(coeffs, output)
        output.write('\n')
```

Obrigado

Comment: Algo me diz que isso é um arquivo JSON. Ora tenta: `import json;with open(coeffs_csv) as f:;data = json.load(f);` ... Atenção, retirar pontos e virgulas no código, só os coloquei para que saibas onde mudar de linha

Comment: Testei essa solução, porém da um erro de extradata, creio que seja devido ao fato de eu adicionar mais uma linha a cada execução do código quando faço a exportação desses dados para um arquivo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar `eval` pra transformar uma string em seu equivalente Python:

```
minha_lista_str = '[1, 2, "a", 2.3]'
minha_lista = eval(minha_lista_str)
print(minha_lista, type(minha_lista))
# [1, 2, 'a', 2.3] <class 'list'>
```

Então seu código fica:

```
with open(coeffs_csv) as inp:
        signals_coeffs_cluster = [eval(x) for x in inp.readlines()]
```